# Dimension zero of Cohomology Group

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-cohomology

Let $X$ be a complete non-singular curve and $\Omega^1$  the sheaf of regular 1-forms on $X$. Let $g=\dim H^0(X, \Omega^1)$ the genus of $X$. I've read that there are $g$ points $P_1,\cdots, P_g$ on $X$ such that if $D=\sum_{i=1}^{g} P_i$,

$\dim H^0(X, \Omega^1\otimes \mathcal{O}_X(-D))=0$.

Here, $\mathcal{O}_X(-D)$ is the associated sheaf to the divisor $D$ on $X$.

I don't understand why this divisor exists.

Comment: Have you considered the canonical degree $g$ map to $\mathbb{P}^1$?

Comment: Here is a general observation. If $L$ is a line bundle on a smooth projective curve with $H^0(L)$ positive dimensional, then for a general point $P$, $\dim H^0(L(-P))=\dim H^0(L)-1$.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. @Mohan, do you know where I can find more about this fact or how this can be proved?