# Dimension of cohomology group of sheaves associated to a point: $dimH^0(L(−P))=dimH^0(L)−1$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology

Could anybody help me with this theorem?

Let $L$ be a line bundle on a smooth projective curve with $H^0(L)$ positive dimensional, then for a general point P, $dimH^0(L(−P))=dimH^0(L)−1$.

I don't know how to prove this. Does anybody know an idea or a reference? In Hartshornes proof of the Riemann-Roch-Theorem for curves there is a similar equality for the Euler-characteristic:

$\chi(L(P))=\chi(L)+1$

Comment: Hint: use the ideal sheaf sequence for $P$, twisted by $L$.

Comment: Using your $$\chi(L(P)) = \chi(L) + 1$$ with $L(-P)$ instead of $L$ and using the definition $\chi := H^0 - H^1$ (on curves), one immediately sees that the desired result is equivalent to showing $\dim H^1(L) = \dim H^1(L(-P))$. Of course you get the same insight by looking at the exact sequence and the resulting long exact sequence.

Comment: Thanks, I see this equivalence. If I choose $L$ as the trivial line bundle I know that $dim H^1(L)=g$ where g is the genus of the curve. Is this right for $dim H^1(L(-P))$, too?

Comment: see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1407764/dimension-zero-of-cohomology-group#comment2868209_1407764 For example, fix an effective divisor $D$ of $L$ (since $h^0(L)>0$, these exist). Take $P$ to be any point in the support of $D$ and check that for such points, what you want is true.